# R^2 (coefficient of deternimation) calculation using numpy and sklearn are giving different results

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I need to calculate the coefficient of determination for a linear regression model.

And I got a strange thing, result of calculation using [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) and `numpy` functions differs to [`sklearn.metrics.r2_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html#sklearn-metrics-r2-score) result.
This code presents the difference :

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

y_true = np.array([2, -0.5, 2.5, 3, 0])
y_pred = np.array([2.5, 0.0, 3, 8, 0])

r2_score(y_true, y_pred)

>>> -1.6546391752577323
```

```
def my_r2_score(y_true, y_pred):
    return 1 - np.sum((y_true - y_pred) ** 2) / np.sum((np.average(y_true) - y_true) ** 2)

def my_r2_score_var(y_true, y_pred):
    return 1 - np.var(y_true - y_pred) / np.var(y_true)

print(my_r2_score(y_true, y_pred))
print(my_r2_score_var(y_true, y_pred))

>>>-1.6546391752577323
>>>-0.7835051546391754
```

Can any body explain this difference ?

Comment: R^2 takes values between 0 and 1, so `my_r2_score` is definitely wrong.

Comment: @vojtam `my_r2_score` is correct. Negative R2 happens when the model predicts worse than just always predicting the average of `y_true`. What you read on the internet about R^2 always being between 0 and 1 is simply incorrect, even for linear models.

Comment: @timgeb No, R^2 is always on (0,1). You probably mean Adjusted R^2 which can be negative.

Comment: @vojtam Sorry this is incorrect. Consider the following dataset. `x = [0, 1, 2]`, `y_true = [1, 2, 1]`. To predict `y_true` we use the really bad linear model `y_pred(x) = 3*x + 1`, i.e. `y_pred = [1, 4, 7]`. This gives us RSS = 40 and TSS = 2/3. So R^2 = 1 - RSS/TSS = -59.

Comment: @timgeb Sorry, you are right. I have just never met a model with negative R^2, but now I see that its theoretically possible. Thanks!

Comment: @vojtam no worries! Here's a cool answer on the topic: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/12991

Answer (score 2):

`my_r2_score_var` is wrong, because `np.sum((y_true - y_pred) ** 2)/5` is not equal to `np.var(y_true - y_pred)`.

```
>>> np.sum((y_true - y_pred) ** 2)/5
5.15
>>> np.var(y_true - y_pred)
3.46
```

What you are doing with `np.var(y_true - y_pred)` is:

```
>>> np.sum(((y_true - y_pred) - np.average(y_true - y_pred))**2)/5
3.46
```

`np.sum((y_true - y_pred) ** 2)` is the correct RSS.

You assumed `np.var(y_true - y_pred)` to be the mean RSS (RSS/5 here), but it isn't.

However, `np.var(y_true)` happens to be the mean TSS. So you got the RSS part of the `1 - RSS/TSS` formula wrong.